# Changes in @Published ObservableObject not updating Views

Tags: swiftui, core-location, swiftui-environment

I know there are a ton of similar threads, however after three weeks I cannot get this code working. Perhaps Stack Overflow can see an obvious error.

Source of truth comes from this ObservableObject class where a locationManager function updates the @Published variable according to the current geoFence.

```
class MapViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    @Published var sceneAccordingToMap = 0
    
      func var1toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 1
      }
      
      func var2toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 2
          
      }

      func var3toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 3
      }

    // Bunch of Irrelevant GeoFencing Code

           *
           *
           *
           

 
    // enter safe area (region)

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Entered: \(region.identifier) ")

        if (region.identifier == "SafeArea"){
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var1toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
        }

        else if (region.identifier == "SafeArea2"){
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var2toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
        }
    }
    
    // exiting safe area (region)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Left: \(region.identifier) ")
        if (region.identifier == "SafeArea"){
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var1toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
        }
        
        else if (region.identifier == "SafeArea2"){
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var2toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
        }
    }  
}
```

Now when passing this @Published variable to a View containing a @StateObject variable, the data is initially passed, however it fails to update when changed by the functions the MapViewModel. The variables are changing, just not in the View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var dataFromMap = MapViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            MapView().ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            Text("\(dataFromMap.sceneAccordingToMap)")
                .padding()

        }

        .environmentObject(MapViewModel())
// Changed to 
        .environmentObject(dataFromMap)
        
    }
}
```

Full code of MapView Model:

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Combine



// map defaults
enum mapDefaults {
    static let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -37.81785423438109, longitude:  144.97973738630145)
    static let initialSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01)
}

class MapViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    @Published var sceneAccordingToMap = 0
    
      func var1toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 1
      }
      
      func var2toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 2
          
      }
      
      func var3toggle() {
          sceneAccordingToMap = 3
      }

    
    
    @Published private(set) var authorizationStatus: UNAuthorizationStatus?
    
    @Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: mapDefaults.initialLocation,
        span: mapDefaults.initialSpan)
    
    var userLatitude = CLLocationCoordinate2D().latitude
    var userLongitude = CLLocationCoordinate2D().longitude
    
    var initialCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var movedCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    @Published var distanceInMeter : Double = 0.0
    

    
    let locations = [
       Location(name: "Safearea", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.331702, longitude:  -122.030785)),
       Location(name: "SafeArea2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.330709, longitude:  -122.030459))

    
    // Create Geofence Region with 10 meter radius
    let geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.331702, longitude:  -122.030785),
                                          radius: 15,
                                          identifier: "SafeArea")
    
    let geofenceRegion2 = CLCircularRegion(center:  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.330709, longitude:  -122.030459),
                                          radius: 15,
                                          identifier: "SafeArea2")



    
    var circle = MKCircle(center: mapDefaults.initialLocation, radius: 10)
    
    var locationMangager: CLLocationManager?
    
    
    // check if location permission is enabled or not
    func checkLocationEnabled() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationMangager = CLLocationManager()
            locationMangager!.delegate = self
            locationMangager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationMangager?.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)
            locationMangager?.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion2)
            print("Location permission enabled")
        }
        else{
            print("Location permission not enabled")
        }
    }
    // Check if user authorized location
    private func checkLocationAuth() {
        guard let locationMangager = locationMangager else {
            return
        }
        
        switch locationMangager.authorizationStatus{
            
        case .notDetermined:
            locationMangager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("User location access is restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("User denied location access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationMangager.location!.coordinate, span: mapDefaults.initialSpan)
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // Check if user changed location after first time
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        //check for location authorization
        checkLocationAuth()
        
        // request for notification access
        requestAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        let location = locations.last
        
        userLatitude = location!.coordinate.latitude
        userLongitude = location!.coordinate.longitude
        
        // Starting position
        initialCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLatitude , longitude: userLongitude)
        // Updated position
        movedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude , longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        self.distanceInMeter = Double(movedCoordinate!.distance(to: initialCoordinate!))
        print(distanceInMeter)
    }
  
    
    // enter safe area (region)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Entered: \(region.identifier) ")

        if (region.identifier == "SafeArea"){
            print("we in pew pew pew pew")
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var1toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)

        }

        else if (region.identifier == "SafeArea2"){
            print("we in doof doof doof")
            
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            
            var2toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)


        }
    }
    
    // exiting safe area (region)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Left: \(region.identifier) ")
        if (region.identifier == "SafeArea"){
            print("we outta pew pew pew pew")
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var1toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)


        }
        
        else if (region.identifier == "SafeArea2"){
            print("we outta doof doof doof")
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)
            var2toggle()
            print(sceneAccordingToMap)


        }
    }

    // request for notification
    func requestAuthorization() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { isGranted, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.authorizationStatus = isGranted ? .authorized : .denied
            }
        }
    }
    
    // create user notification
    func triggerLocalNotification(subTitle: String, body: String){
        // configure notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Alert!"
        content.subtitle = subTitle
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        // setup trigger
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        
        // create request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        // add notification request
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
         if let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay {
           let renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: tileOverlay)
           return renderer
         }
         return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
   
   
// return distance in meters
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    
    /// Returns the distance between two coordinates in meters.
    func distance(to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        MKMapPoint(self).distance(to: MKMapPoint(to))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have two instances of `MapViewModel`

Comment: Hi @jnpdx, thanks for pointing it out. Where is the second instance? Do you mean I should pass the dataFromMap instance instead of MapViewModel() in the .environmentObject() modifier? I tried that with no success. Excuse me please, I'm still learning.

Comment: Yes, you should only create MapViewModel once. Right now, you create it on the `@StateObject` declaration and on the `environmentObject()`. Beyond this, there's really not enough to represent the problem. Where does the location manager get started? Have you used the debugger to see if the callback functions are called?

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx , makes a lot of sense. I added the entire MapViewModel for you to see. I used print statements to debug. According to these the Published variable gets  correctly updated each time a geofence barrier is crossed.

Comment: What happens if you surround any call of `sceneAccordingToMap =` with `Task { @MainActor in ... }`

Comment: Changed the func's inside MapViewModel to `Task { @MainActor in sceneAccordingToMap = 1 }`

Still no update on ContentView() however. I really appreciate all the advice @jnpdx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248664/discussion-between-theuns-botha-and-jnpdx).